# PyQt: Force popup window to be at the front

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a simple popup about window in my application. It has a button "Ok" which closes the about window. I want to make that window 'exitable' only via the "Ok" button so you wouldn't be able to un-focus and get out of it.

That would be the same behavior as Internet Explorer about window.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The code!

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from os import system, chdir,getcwd
    from time import sleep
    from subprocess import Popen
    
    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s
    
    try:
        _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
    
            
    class MyPopup(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("./about.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.setWindowIcon(icon)
            resolution = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
            self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),(resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))
            pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            pic.setGeometry(20, 20, 128, 128)
            pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(getcwd() + "/icon.png"))
            self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 300))
            self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 300))
            labele = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            labele.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(158, 20 , 2000, 50))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(26)
            labele.setText(_translate("MyPopup", "Auto Shutdown", None))
            labele.setFont(font)
            
            labelel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            labelel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(158, 70 , 2000, 25))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(16)
            labelel.setText(_translate("MyPopup", "Jan Murić", None))
            labelel.setFont(font)
            
            
            labelo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            labelo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 175 , 300, 100))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(10)
            labelo.setText(_translate("MyPopup", "FREEWARE\n\nVersion:  1.0\nE-Mail:        janek.muric@gmail.com", None))
            labelo.setFont(font)
            
            exitButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
            exitButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(347, 276, 71, 23))
            exitButton.setText(_translate("MyPopup", "Ok", None))
            exitButton.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        
        def quit(self):
            self.close()
            
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    
        global x
        x = 0
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow, parent=None):
            super(Ui_MainWindow, self)
            MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
            MainWindow.resize(261, 390)
            MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
            MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("./icon.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
            MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
            self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
            self.action = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
            self.action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(104, 60, 91, 22))
            self.action.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("action"))
            self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
            self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
            self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
            self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
            self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 221, 21))
            self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
            self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 51, 21))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
            self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
            self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 241, 191))
            self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
            self.selectTime = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
            self.selectTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 82, 17))
            self.selectTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectTime"))
            self.buttonGroup_2 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)
            self.buttonGroup_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonGroup_2"))
            self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectTime)
            self.selectDate = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
            self.selectDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 82, 17))
            self.selectDate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectDate"))
            self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectDate)
            self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
            self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(116, 60, 61, 20))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(10)
            self.label_3.setFont(font)
            self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
            self.relativeTime = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
            self.relativeTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 61, 22))
            self.relativeTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("relativeTime"))
            self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
            self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 21, 21))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(10)
            self.label_4.setFont(font)
            self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
            self.dateTime = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
            self.dateTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 111, 22))
            self.dateTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateTime"))
            self.forceCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
            self.forceCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 81, 21))
            self.forceCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("forceCheck"))
            self.forceCheck.stateChanged.connect(self.changeText)
            self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 300, 71, 23))
            self.startButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startButton"))
            self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
            self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 330, 251, 20))
            self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
            self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 360, 261, 20))
            self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
            self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.dateTime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
            self.about = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.about.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 21, 21))
            self.about.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("about"))
            self.about.clicked.connect(self.aboutWindow)
            global tim
            global act
            global forc
            tim = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
            tim = str(tim.hour()) + ":" + str(tim.minute())
            act = "Shut Down"
            forc = ""
            self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
            self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
            self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.selectTime.toggled.connect(self.greyOut2)
            self.selectDate.toggled.connect(self.greyOut1)
            self.action.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeText)
            self.dateTime.dateTimeChanged.connect(self.changeText)
            self.relativeTime.timeChanged.connect(self.changeText)
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Shutdown", None))
            self.action.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Shut Down", None))
            self.action.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Restart", None))
            self.action.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Go to boot menu", None))
            self.action.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Hibernate", None))
            self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please chose an action and then a time for it.", None))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action:", None))
            self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Time Schedule", None))
            self.selectTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Relative Time", None))
            self.selectDate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exact Time", None))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "From now", None))
            self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On", None))
            self.forceCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Force Action", None))
            self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start", None))
            self.about.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?", None))
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " in ", None))
            self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow",  tim + forc, None))
            self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
    
        
        def greyOut1(self): #selectDate on
            self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
            self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.label_4.setEnabled(True)
            self.dateTime.setEnabled(True)
            self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
            
        def greyOut2(self): #selectTime on
            self.label_3.setEnabled(True)
            self.relativeTime.setEnabled(True)
            self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
            self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        def changeText(self):
            if self.selectDate.isChecked():
                global forc
                if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                    forc = " (Force)"
                else:
                    forc = ""
                
                act = self.action.currentText()
                tim = self.dateTime.dateTime()
                timm = tim.time()
                dat = tim.date()
                timee = str(dat.day()) + "." + str(dat.month()) + "." + str(dat.year()) + " " + str(timm.hour()) + ":" + str(timm.minute())
                self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " at ", None))
                self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", timee + " " + forc,None))
            else:
                if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                    forc = "(Force)"
                else:
                    forc = ""
                
                act = self.action.currentText()
                tim = self.relativeTime.time()
                now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
                hr = now.hour() + tim.hour()
                mn = now.minute() + tim.minute()
                timee = str(hr) + ":" + str(mn)
                self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " at ", None))
                self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", timee + forc,None))
            
        def start(self):
            global x
            if x == 0:
                x = 1
                palette = QtGui.QPalette()
                palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground,QtCore.Qt.darkGreen)
                self.label_5.setPalette(palette)
                self.label_6.setPalette(palette)
                self.startButton.setText("Stop")
                self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
                self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
                self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
                self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
                self.action.setEnabled(False)
                self.selectTime.setEnabled(False)
                self.selectDate.setEnabled(False)
                self.forceCheck.setEnabled(False)
                
                global f
                global t
                global s
                if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                    f = " /f"
                    
                else:
                    f = ""
                    
                if self.action.currentText() == "Shut Down":
                    s = "/s"
                    
                elif self.action.currentText() == "Restart":
                    s = "/r"
                elif self.action.currentText() == "Go to boot menu":
                    s = "/o"
                elif self.action.currentText() == "Hibernate":
                    s = "/h"
                
                if self.selectTime.isChecked():
                    tim = self.relativeTime.time()
                    now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
                    
                    timm = int(tim.hour())
                    tinn = int(tim.minute())
                    hsec = timm * 60
                    hsec = hsec * 60
                    msec = tinn * 60
                    t = msec + hsec
                    chdir(".")
                    Popen("shutdwn " + s + " /t " + str(t) + f)
                if self.selectDate.isChecked():
    
                    tim = self.dateTime.dateTime()
                    now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
                    t = tim.toTime_t() - now.toTime_t()
                    Popen("shutdwn " + s + " /t " + str(t) + f)
    
            
            
            
            else:
                x = 0
                palette = QtGui.QPalette()
                palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground,QtCore.Qt.black)
                self.label_5.setPalette(palette)
                self.label_6.setPalette(palette)
                chdir(".")
                Popen("shutdwn /a")
                self.action.setEnabled(True)
                self.selectTime.setEnabled(True)
                self.selectDate.setEnabled(True)
                self.forceCheck.setEnabled(True)    
                self.startButton.setText("Start")   
        
        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
        def aboutWindow(self):
            self.w = MyPopup()
            self.w.show()
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help.

Comment: @TimWakeham There we go! I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Mypopup class extend QDialog then call _exec function it will make your popup modal so you wont be able to interact with rest of application without dealing popup first

```
class MyPopup(QDialog):
    Qdialog.__init__.(self)
//and on your aboutWindow function call _exec function
self.w.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheriting from `QWidget`, use a `QDialog` with `setModal(True)`.

```
class MyPopup(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setModal(True)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your popup modal by having it inherit from `QDialog` rather than `QWidget` then show it with `self.w.exec_()`

Not sure if you want the dialog close button (X) to be disabled or hidden completely, but you can see if `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` does what you want.

Comment: Seems like a nice idea (FramelessWindowHInt)! But I keep getting an error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FramelessWindowHint'"
This happends when I try with Qt, QtGui and QCore. None of them have FrameLessWindowHint attribute? :/

Comment: `from PyQt4.Qtcore import Qt`